# Java MySQL Select Query

Tags: java, sql

below I have got the code for the connector, then i have code for another class called viewHistory. now, what i was trying to do is to enable a user to enter a studentID number, and then the relevant attendance history should come up. It's however compiloing but giving me an error message when i type in a number to check if it shows anything. Any suggestion?

```
public class Connector {
Connection con;
PreparedStatement stmt;
ResultSet rs;

Connector()
{
    try{


        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/luxmidatabase","root","");
                    stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from login where username=? and password=?");
                    }

    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

**2nd CLASS**

```
public class AttendanceHistory extends Connector
{

public AttendanceHistory() {
    initialize();
}

public JFrame frmAttendanceHistory;

Connector con;
private JTextField textField;

// initialise the frame
private void initialize() {
    frmAttendanceHistory = new JFrame();
    frmAttendanceHistory.setTitle("LEC AdminPro: Attendance History");
    frmAttendanceHistory.setBounds(100, 100, 323, 149);
    frmAttendanceHistory.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    frmAttendanceHistory.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    // Initialising a Grey Border, which I am going to be using later to add borders to JLabels.
    Border border = LineBorder.createGrayLineBorder();
    frmAttendanceHistory.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    con = new Connector();

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBounds(0, 0, 307, 113);
    frmAttendanceHistory.getContentPane().add(panel_1);
    panel_1.setBorder(border);
    panel_1.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblRegister = new JLabel("View Attendance History");
    lblRegister.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    lblRegister.setBounds(10, 11, 193, 20);
    panel_1.add(lblRegister);

    JLabel lblStudentId = new JLabel("Student ID");
    lblStudentId.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    lblStudentId.setBounds(10, 45, 69, 14);
    panel_1.add(lblStudentId);

    // Created a Cancel button along with an OptionDialog which pops up to confirm whether user wants to cancel registration or not.
    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Cancel");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Object[] options = {"Yes", "No"};
            Component form = null;
            int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(form, "Would you like to cancel the progress?", "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,  null, options, options);
            if(n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                frmAttendanceHistory.setVisible(false);
            }

        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(159, 73, 75, 23);
    panel_1.add(btnNewButton);

    JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


        //String studentID = textField.getText();   

        try {


            con.stmt.executeQuery("SELECT StudentID, date FROM attendance WHERE StudentID = 21457");            
            while ( rs.next() ) {
                String date = rs.getString("date");
                System.out.println(date);
            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmAttendanceHistory, "Attendance has been registered.");
            frmAttendanceHistory.setVisible(false);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
        //System.out.println("Record couldn't be added!");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmAttendanceHistory, "Attendance couldn't be registered. Please try again!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        });



    button.setBounds(81, 73, 75, 23);
    panel_1.add(button);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(81, 42, 212, 20);
    panel_1.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);




}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
            AttendanceHistory window = new AttendanceHistory();
            window.frmAttendanceHistory.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}



// method to make this frame visible (may be used in other classes for retrieval)
public void setVisible(boolean b) {
    frmAttendanceHistory.setVisible(true);

}    
}
```

Main Issue is the code inside the Submit Button. Thats where I try to filter the data.

This is the error Message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at AttendanceHistory$2.actionPerformed(AttendanceHistory.java:85)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: All together now: What is the error message?

Comment: @JacobM I have provided the error message above.

Comment: `NullPointerException` happens because something is `null` that should not be `null`. Look at the error message. It tells you exactly where it happens: in line 85 of `AttendanceHistory.java`. Look at that part of the code.

Comment: @Jesper - could you please advise what could be wrong? because this is what i got in line 85:     while ( rs.next() ) {   - i really dont understand what could be wrong?

Comment: what is the `con.stmt.executeQuery...` in your `AttendanceHistory` ? I guess you are trying to execute a statement in the `Connector` class's stmt, but this is not what actually is happening. Refactor your code for better understanding. create a `Connector c=new Connector();` and then try `ResultSet rs=c.stmt.executeQuery();`

Comment: Hi @prajeeshkumar - how should i correct it then? could you please advise?

Comment: I have edited my earlier comment with details, check it

Comment: Hi @prajeeshkumar - thank you. i have tried this. compiles again but now a different error message beginning with : java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

Comment: Hmmm, you have in your preparedStatement `username=? and password=?`. I think you need to do this differently like `Statement st=c.con.createStatement();` and then `ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT StudentID, date FROM attendance WHERE StudentID = 21457");`

Comment: It works now @Prajeesh Kumar. I have one more question. Temporarily i have put in this code:     ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT StudentID, date FROM attendance WHERE StudentID = 21457");     INSTEAD of 21457 there should be textField.getText() the value whatever the user types in. how can i amend this in the code? I tried     ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT StudentID, date FROM attendance WHERE StudentID = textField.getText()");
 but it doesnt work.

Comment: `ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT StudentID, date FROM attendance WHERE StudentID = "+textField.getText());` will work

Comment: @prajeeshkumar - and finally, if i want to say, if the resultset for the given id is null or empty then display an error message. to check whether its empty. Can i write if (rs = 0) { ERROR MESSAGE }

Comment: I got it myself, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments you said that the line where the error happens is

```
while ( rs.next() ) {
```

The `NullPointerException` happens because `rs` is `null`. I don't see that you're initializing `rs` anywhere in your code. Probably the line above should have been:

```
ResultSet rs = con.stmt.executeQuery(...);
```

(Where are you declaring the variable `rs`?).

Another problem: You're re-using the `Statement` object that you had prepared in the `Connector` object with the `select * from login ...` SQL. You should create a new statement to execute the query instead. Something like this:

```
Statement st = con.con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT StudentID, date from ...");
while (rs.hasNext()) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that you should also properly discard the `Statement` and `ResultSet` objects by calling `close()` on them. (Preferably in a `finally` block so that it happens even in case of an exception).

Comment: I have only got ResultSet rs; in the connector class. I shall try the method you mentioned.

Comment: @PitaSivam Then it's indeed going to be `null` in line 85, if you're not assigning it another value.

Comment: Hi @Jesper - thank you. i have tried this. compiles again but now a different error message beginning with : java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

Comment: @PitaSivam Another problem is that you are re-using the statement that you prepared in the `Connector` class. You'll need to create a new `Statement` for the query. I'll update my answer above.

Comment: one more question. Where it says     ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT StudentID, date FROM attendance WHERE StudentID = 21457");

Instead of 21457 i want there to be textField.getText() - so the actual value that is typed into the field. how can i mention this in the code? any suggestion?

Comment: @PitaSivam Use a `PreparedStatement` and set the value appropriately. `int id = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()); PreparedStatement st = con.con.prepareStatement("SELECT ... WHERE StudentId=?"); st.setInt(1, id); ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();`